# What's the best bound for $\sum_{i=0}^{[\lg{n}]}{\binom{n}{2^{i}}}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality

I want to find best lower bound and upper bound for:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{[\lg{n}]}{\binom{n}{2^{i}}}$$

Comment: how do you define upper bound? I mean whether it is a function of n or a number for all n bounded.

Comment: @Zack its hard to understand the amount of it I want to find upper and lower bound that work easy with it

Comment: So you mean the upper bound is a function of $n$? I think one of the best upper bound should be $2^n$ because the binomial theorem comes in handy. However, how do you define the best? I have totally no idea.

Comment: @ZackNi $2^{n}$ is too large for it!

Comment: Yes of course that's why I feel really unease and anxious. After this clarification, your question becomes clear. Find the upper bound with the biggest distance from $2^n$ and less than 2^n.

Comment: The main contribute to the sum comes from the power of $2$ that is closest to $n/2$, so we have strong oscillations according to $n$ being close or not to a power of $2$ and no tight upper bound holding for every $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JackD'Aurizio states, the sum is dominated by the choices of $i$ for which $2^i$ is closest to $\frac{n}{2}$.  Let $a = \left\lfloor \lg \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor = \lfloor \lg n \rfloor - 1$.  This gives the largest $i$ for which $2^i \le \frac{n}{2}$.  The terms we should focus on are then $i = a$ and $i = a + 1$.

(To see that the other terms are insignificant, observe $\binom{n}{r-1} = \frac{r}{n-r} \binom{n}{r} \le \frac12 \binom{n}{r}$, provided $r \le \frac{n}{3}$.  Moreover, since $\frac{n}{4} < 2^a \le \frac{n}{2}$, we have at least $\frac{n}{12}$ values of $r$ for which $2^{a-1} < r \le \frac{n}{3}$.  Thus for each of the summands with $i < a$, we have
$$ \binom{n}{2^i} \le \binom{n}{2^{a-1}} = \binom{n}{2^a} \prod_{r = 2^{a-1} + 1}^{2^a} \frac{\binom{n}{r-1}}{\binom{n}{r}} \le 2^{- n/12 } \binom{n}{2^a}. $$

Hence the sum $\sum_{i < a} \binom{n}{2^i} < \lg n \cdot 2^{- n / 12} \binom{n}{2^a}$ is exponentially small compared to $\binom{n}{2^a}$.)

Now note that we have $a = \lfloor \lg n \rfloor - 1 = \lg n - \{ \lg n \} - 1$, where for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\{ x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.  Hence $2^a = 2^{\lg n - \{ \lg n \} - 1} = cn$, where $c = 2^{ - \{ \lg n \} - 1 }$.  We also have $2^{a+1} = 2cn$.

Now, using Stirling's Approximation, when $k, n \rightarrow \infty$, one has
$$ \binom{n}{k} \sim \sqrt{ \frac{n}{2 \pi k (n-k) } } \left( \frac{n}{k} \right)^k \left( \frac{n }{n-k} \right)^{n-k}. $$

When $k = \gamma n$, for some $\gamma \in (0,1)$, this simplifies to
$$ \binom{n}{\gamma n} \sim \left( 2 \pi \gamma (1 - \gamma) n \right)^{- 1/2} \left( \gamma^{\gamma} (1 - \gamma)^{1 - \gamma} \right)^{-n}.$$

Putting everything together, it follows that
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor} \binom{n}{2^i} \sim \left( 2 \pi c (1 - c) n \right)^{- 1/2} \left( c^c (1 - c)^{1 - c} \right)^{-n} + \left( 4 \pi c (1 - 2c) n \right)^{- 1/2} \left( (2c)^{2c} (1 - 2c)^{1 - 2c} \right)^{-n},$$
where $c = 2^{ - \{ \lg n \} - 1}$.

Now of course that is a horrible expression.  What is more useful is to compare this to $2^n$.  The binary entropy $H(x)$ is defined by $H(x) = -x \lg x - (1-x) \lg (1 - x)$.  Then the term $ \left( c^c (1-c)^{1-c} \right)^{-n} = 2^{H(c) n}$, and similarly the other term is $2^{H(2c)n}$.  The leading square root factors are insignificant compared to these exponential terms.  Hence we find that the order of magnitude of the sum is given by
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor} \binom{n}{2^i} = \Theta \left( n^{-1/2} 2^{ f(n) n } \right), $$
where $f(n) = \max \left( H(c), H(2c) \right)$, where $c = 2^{- \{ \lg n \} - 1}$.

Below is a graph showing the values $f(n)$ takes as $\{ \lg n \}$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ (thanks, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)!):
[image: Graph of $f(n)$]

So you can see when $\{ \lg n \} \approx 0,1$ (that is, when $n$ is close to a power of $2$), we can get $2^i \approx \frac{n}{2}$, which means the order of magnitude is roughly $2^n / \sqrt{n}$.  This is not too far from the trivial upper bound of $2^n$.

On the other hand, for more moderate values of $\{ \lg n \}$ (that is, when $n$ is far from a power of $2$), the constant in the exponent drops.  The minimum constant is achieved when $\{ \lg n \} \approx 0.585$, when $2^a \approx \frac{n}{3}$ and $2^{a+1} \approx \frac{2n}{3}$ are both simultaneously as far from $\frac{n}{2}$ as possible.  Here the sum is of the order of magnitude roughly $2^{0.918n} / \sqrt{n}$, which is of course exponentially smaller than $2^n$.

[Sorry I can't give a more elegant answer, but these binomial calculations usually require getting your hands dirty.]

Comment: Its so beautiful ! Tanks about your answer!

Comment: Haha, I guess beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  You're welcome!